# Bash: terminating the current process and execute the command again

Tags: bash, shell, keyboard-shortcuts

There is a process running in my bash, namely 'foo' for example. Is there a shortcut that can terminate the process and execute it again, at once?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming, and better suited on http://unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: Do you mean Ctrl+C, Cursor up, Return?

Comment: @Cyrus : He's asking for a shortcut which would do something equivalent to (Ctrl+C, CursorUp, Return) at one shot.

Comment: @Cyrus Yes, but not three steps, is there an one-step solution?

Answer (score 0):

CTRL + c will terminate your current process. After that, you can use "!!" shortcut to execute the lastest command.